# is there a fastest option to cp files from dir1 to dir2?

Tags: linux, command, copy-paste

i used **cp** to copy lots of small files (b/n 1M and 10M size; around 6G total) in Linux box. Didn't **time** it but since i am going to do **cp** again and again, can **time** it and be more specific later; but since the **cp** is not the major task, can't tolerate the time it's taking if there is a better option/choice/way. So, if there is a better way/option/method to do **cp**-ing (faster) files from one dir to another, be glad glad to try it out.

Thanks,

Comment: I think you're more likely to get a good answer at serverfault.com

Comment: Do you always need to copy all the files? Depending on your case you might only need to copy a subset of them. If you need to copy all of them and you have a slow network connection, think about compressing them into an archive, copy that, then decompress on the target system. Depends on where your bottleneck is, really. And Nathan is right, too :-)

Comment: @TToni the cp is being done from a standalone machine... no socks involved plus for what is worth it is being done in runlevel 1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Either of tar/untar or `rsync` when told not to checksum will be faster, since they bulk-read files instead of handling them one-by-one.

Comment: taring them is not an option, all of the files should be cp-ed naturally without compression, but rsync not sure since the destination dir will be reformatted with a new filesystem every now and then before the cp-ing?

Comment: tar doesn't compress. And it doesn't matter anyways since it's being untarred right after.

Answer (score 1):

You could try [cpio](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cpio#Copy), as that has a copy directory to directory mode.

Answer (score 1):

**use perl** for fastest copy:

```
use File::Copy::syscopy;  # preserves OS specific file attributes
copy($foo,$bar) or die "cannot copy $foo to $bar: $!";  # always check for errors!
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this just backup today's files:

```
find /home/me/files -ctime 0 -print -exec cp {} /mnt/backup/{} \;
```

from:
http://commandperls.com/find-all-today%E2%80%99s-files-and-copy-them-to-another-directory/

Comment: Thanks for the thought but here is the out put of a time command on a 12.4 megabyte size directory as contrasted with cp-r....                                                                     "Ur suggestion output:                             real 0m0.434s
user 0m0.016s
sys 0m0.164s
       cp-r                                                        real 0m0.092s
user 0m0.008s
sys 0m0.056s

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried:

```
time (cd /usr/local/src/ && tar pcf - cvs.gnome.org) | buffer -m 8m -p 75 | (cd /mnt/tmp/src/ && tar pxf -)
```

(Credits: https://lists.debian.org/debian-user/2001/06/msg00288.html)